# which event would notify me that the scrolling is finished in a scroll bar?

Tags: c#

which event would notify me that the scrolling is finished in a scroll bar?
I have a scroll bar in a panel. vScrollBar1_Scroll event tells me that scrolling has started. I want to be notified when it stops. Which event to use in C#?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "scrolling has stopped". Do you want to know if the scroll bar has reached the end or if no more scrolling is occuring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention to [e.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.type%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your Scroll event handler.  It will be ScrollEventType.EndScroll after the user stops dragging the thumb.